# Adding style to SVG shape with a conditional statement

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and I was wondering if there is a way to change the stroke type of a shape to dashed with a conditional statement? How do I target a specific circle and add a new style to it?

```
var num = stageLevelUntrimmed;

if (num == "Stage 1") {
    num = "1";
    .style("stroke-dasharray", ("10,3")) // make the stroke dashed
} else {
    num = "4";
}

g.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", "250")
    .attr("cx", cfg.w / 2)
    .attr("cy", cfg.h / 2)
    .style("fill", ellipsefillOne) 
    .style("stroke", "#FAAF3A")
    .style("stroke-opacity", "0.75")
    .style("stroke-width", "3.5px");
```

This is the style that I want to add if condition one is met:

```
.style("stroke-dasharray", ("10,3")) // make the stroke dashed
```

Comment: Are you missing something in front of the `.style(...`?

Comment: Yes, In front of the `.style` that is in the if statement I'm missing information. I'm trying to figure out how to embed  this style to the existing shape so I don't want to create a new shape and add that missing information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a data model you are binding this to ? perhaps with the `cfg` object?

I would add the value you needed in the data model then as you iterate through use d3 to set the attr. I feel you are missing some code that might help me understand your problem more.

Heres a working plunker [enter link description here](https://plnkr.co/edit/iJ2I9yG7WlxoFpWoh1WI?p=preview)

```
var my_data = [
  {"w":50, "h":50, "num":"Stage 1"},
  {"w":100, "h":100, "num":"Stage 2"},
  {"w":140, "h":200, "num":"Stage 3"},
  {"w":150, "h":300, "num":"Stage 4"}];

var svg = d3.select("#mysvg").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 400);


var circles =  svg.selectAll("circle")
                  .data(my_data)      // iterate through the data object 'my_data'
                  .enter()
                  .append("circle")
                  .attr("r", "25")
                  .attr("cx", function(d){ return d.w / 2.0; } ) // get this components 'w'
                  .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.h / 2.0; } ) //      'h'
                  .style("fill", function(d){ return "red"; } )
                  .style("stroke", "#FAAF3A")
                  .style("stroke-opacity", "0.75")
                  .style("stroke-width", "3.5px")
                  .style("stroke-dasharray", function(d){ 
                    // set the dasharray if condition null means no attr
                    if (d.num === "Stage 1"){
                      return ("10,3") 
                    } 
                    return null;
                  }) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use D3's `filter()` function to achieve what you're looking for, but it requires that you to bind some data to your elements.

For example, say you want to draw 4 circles and you want the first circle to have a dashed stroke:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var r = 40;

// Create the 4 circles with the default style.
svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(d3.range(1, 5))    // d3.range(1, 5) produces [1, 2, 3, 4]
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", r)
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return 2 * r * (i + 1);
  })
  .attr("cy", 100);

// Select only the circle that's bound to the first element.
// Then, apply the dash style.
d3.selectAll("circle")
  .filter(function(d) { return d === 1; })
  .style("stroke-dasharray", "10,3");
```

```css
circle {
  fill: yellow;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg height="300" width="500"></svg>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wy9phjd5/1/)